# PHP $_POST cutting off '<' character coming from $.post in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I feel like this should be easy. The character `<` (and following characters) refuses to be sent to `$_POST`. My max_input_vars is set to 10000, my memory limit is set to 3GB in my php.ini file, and I'm using PHP 8.0.

I have a text area where the text gets posted to a PHP file.

```
# HTML
<div class="add-comment">
    <textarea style="margin-left: -15px;" placeholder="Add your commentary here" style="white-space:pre-wrap;" id="add-comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

# JS
let comment = $('#add-comment').val();
const post_variables = {
    'comment' : comment   
};
console.log(post_variables);
$.post('/?c=comments&a=add_comment', post_variables, function(data){});

# PHP
echo '<pre>post:<br>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Lets say I submit the text `'a < b'`.

In JS, the log shows: `a < b`

In PHP the log shows: `a`

Is there something I need to do before passing it off to PHP? I'm genuinely surprised I haven't run into this before..

Comment: The "<" is a HTML special Character if you see your page source code it is parsed by PHP but the HTML reads it as opening of a tag. Use htmlspecialchars() Convert special characters to HTML entities. 
 For more... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: How can I intercept it before it gets to PHP? Simply doing `htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);` does not work..

Comment: PHP don't parse anything! It is you browser that parse de response send by PHP...

Comment: in php the htmlentities function does the job example :   echo "<pre>".htmlentities(print_r($_POST, true))."</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

You can print the "<" on PHP using print_r(htmlspecialchar($_POST['comment'])) and if you want to convert it before sending to PHP use below function

```
# JS
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}


let comment = $('#add-comment').val();
const post_variables = {
    'comment' : htmlEntities(comment)   
};
```